# Sphere rotation in Babylon.js

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, babylonjs

I want to ask for help regarding rotation using the Babylon.js framework.

I need the sphere to rotate 45 degrees, exactly aligned with the diagonal circle, which has a 45 degree orientation, but I'm not getting it.

The code I made is in the link below:
https://codepen.io/polalas/pen/VwvaKwL

The method responsible for the rotation is the loop () method, which is triggered every time the scene is rendered.

```
function loop () {
    var y1 = scene.getMeshByName("I1");
    y1.rotation.y - = 0.01 * Math.sin (Math.PI / 4);
    y1.rotation.x - = 0.01 * Math.sin (Math.PI / 4);
}
```

I imagine that I mishandled the rotation. Could someone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, the best way to achieve that is to first rotate the parent of the sphere (what you called `newMesh` (or `I1`)) 45 degrees around the Z axis right before adding the sphere as a child:

```js
newMesh.rotate(BABYLON.Axis.Z, Math.PI / 4);
```

Afterwards you can rotate it around its Local (!) X axis in your render loop:

```js
function loop(){
    var y1 = scene.getMeshByName("I1");
}
```

This way you get a perfect rotation around your (mocked) pivot.